# Login to Twitter sometimes fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I use the simple code for login to Twitter

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session != nil) {
            NSLog(@"successful %@",session);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

and sometimes I get the error:

> 2016-08-04 15:39:14.472 MyProject[11143:132894] [TwitterKit] did
>   encounter error with message "Error attempting to obtain temporary
>   auth token.": Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not
>   connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe043a49830
>   {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.} 2016-08-04
>   15:39:14.473 EarCrush[11143:132894] [TwitterKit] did encounter error
>   with message "Unable to authenticate using the system account.": Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe043a49830 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
>
> 2016-08-04 15:39:14.473 MyProject[11143:132894] error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe043a49830 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

I mean sometimes because:

- 2 days ago I can login to Twitter normally
- Yesterday I can not login,
- This morning I can login but now (afternoon) I can not login even I don't   change any code

I have update my Twitter via Fabric to latest version now (2.3) and I'm sure I have internet connection

I know my problem is very strangely but hope someone have a same problem like me can give me some suggestion for fix it

Answer (score 2):

I had problem with login with Twitter and Firebase. This code working for me:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("key", consumerSecret: "secret")
```

in AppDelegate. Then, when you tap on your custom login button call this:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion() { session, error in
        if let session = session { ... })
```

If you using Fabric, you don't need to call Fabric.with([Twitter.self]).

Comment: I'm really sorry because I'm not working with Twitter now so I can not test it, but if many person vote on this question I will accept it. Thank for your help

Comment: I had a lot of problems with login with Twitter + Firebase, so maybe it will be helpful for some others.